# Missing Nvidia Settings Application

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Laptop : Lenovo y520

Secure Boot : Disabled

Desktop Environment : KDE Plasma & Gnome

Nvidia Driver : 460 ( GTX 1060 6GB)

So I just installed ubuntu and found out the nvidia drivers were already installed, so I changed the profile to the intel one to save battery power. However, when I did this I was met with this nvidia smi error:

[image]

But for some reason I can still change profiles normally using the terminal like so:

[image]

Here is what I get if I run the nvidia settings using the console:

[image]

[image]

Apologies for asking this but all the other answers were really outdated or didn't work

Comment: I didn't though. I can enable the nvidia profile again via the console, but not using the application. Besides, the last paragraph describes exactly what I did.

Comment: "I change profile to the Intel..." does not tell us what you actually did. You should be specific and detailed. We shouldn't have to guess what you mean by that, so be explicit in what exact steps you took.

Comment: Use copy-paste to share commands and output.  You can use backticks or the formatting tools to render the text as `monospace`.  Do not submit pictures of any text including your terminal

Comment: I installed bumblebee, if that helps

Comment: I suggest that you revert the changes you made back to how they were before the problem started. See if that makes a difference .

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this issue, this means that KDE or any other desktop environment you installed has conflicted with gnome. I fixed this by completely purging kubuntu desktop. Also, if you get a "Ubuntu on Wayland" DE that means you installed nvidia correctly. I hope this helps anyone who encounters this issue.